# Asset Changes in v3.0

Tags: plugin-development

This is primarily directed to P&T, but I'm working on a project which is heavily using/extending Craft Assets.  I noticed in the Asset Service there is a reference to breaking changes in Craft 3.0.  I don't want to get too far down the road with this to realize it will have to be refactored.

I'm sure you're not willing to give a 3.0 release date, but any indication to what these change will look like or when they will happen is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Craft’s assets functionality is getting refactored in Craft 3, so anything you do with those APIs today will need to be updated when 3.0 comes out.

The silver lining for you is, literally *every* plugin will need to be updated for Craft 3 (due to us moving to Yii 2), so we are planning on having a several month-long beta period where we will work with plugin developers to get their plugins updated, before the official public release. So we will be happy to work with you on updating your plugin during that period.

As far as an ETA, I couldn’t say. Craft 2 still has a lot of shelf life ahead of it.

Comment: Craft moving to Yii 2 is very exciting!  We'll proceed as planned and cross the need to update when we get there.

Comment: Is there any official email developer plugin list you can sign up to? Have some self made Plugins that would need to be updated :)

Comment: @naboovalley No - it will be a public beta and we will be communicating publicly about this stuff when the time comes.